# JSP - error getting class enum type property

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, jpa

I have a problem accesing `public enum` class properties inside my JSP page. I am able to access all other's invite class properties except `invite.status` attribute. I am doing something wrong, but i just can't figure why it is wrong and how i can access my returned list's `enum` values. Thanks for your help solving my issue!

Error what I get The class `...domain.jpa.meeting.Invite`' does not have the property `status`.

This is JPA class that I have

```
@Entity
public class Invite implements PersistentEntity  {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User inviter;

    @ManyToOne
    private User invitee;

    @ManyToOne
    private Meeting meeting;

    /**
     * Date when this invite has been created
     */
    private Date created;

//      @Column(nullable=false, length=1)
//  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private InviteStatus status;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public User getInviter() {
        return inviter;
    }

    public void setInviter(User inviter) {
        this.inviter = inviter;
    }

    public User getInvitee() {
        return invitee;
    }

    public void setInvitee(User invitee) {
        this.invitee = invitee;
    }

    public Meeting getMeeting() {
        return meeting;
    }

    public void setMeeting(Meeting meeting) {
        this.meeting = meeting;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public InviteStatus getInviteStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setInviteStatus(InviteStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

This is enum type public class that i have

```
/**
 * Values for tracking invite status
 */
public enum InviteStatus {

    // invite is created and invitee have not responded yet
    CREATED,

    // invitee accepted this invite
    ACCEPTED,

    // invitee declined this invite
    DECLINED
}
```

I am saving in database such way (with success as EnumType.ORDINAL)

```
// adding invites (table invite)
Invite invite = new Invite();
invite.setInviter(creator);
User invitee = jpaDAO.getById(User.class, Long.parseLong(friends[i]));
invite.setInvitee(invitee);
invite.setInviteStatus(InviteStatus.CREATED); //CREATED = 0, ACCEPTED = 1, ..
Date dateNow = new Date(); //yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
invite.setCreated(dateNow);
Meeting meeting = jpaDAO.getById(Meeting.class, meetingId);
invite.setMeeting(meeting);
jpaDAO.save(invite);
```

And i have a method which retrieves invites from database.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "null" })
public List<Invite> getUserInvites(Long userId){
// getting invites for current user with status CREATED
Query query = jpaDAO.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(JPQConst.InviteJpq.QUERY_GET_BY_USER);
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
List<Invite> invites = (List<Invite>) query.getResultList();
return invites;
}
```

Inside controller it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Display Notifications tab
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/home/notifications", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayNotifications(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    User user = getCurrentUser(session);        
    List<Invite> invites = notificationService.getUserInvites(user.getId());
    model.addAttribute("invites", invites);
    return "home";
}
```

Method itself works, and I am able to access all invite's property fields except status property inside jsp.

```
<c:forEach var="meeting" items="${inviteeMeetings}">
    <c:forEach var="invite" items="${invites}">
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${meeting.id == invite.meeting.id}">
            <tr>
                <td width="150px" align="center">
                    <c:out value="${meeting.startTime}" />
                </td>
                <td width="396px">
                    <a href="../meeting/${meeting.id}"><c:out value="${meeting.title}" /></a>
                </td>
                <td width="96px">
                    <c:out value="${invite.status}" />
                    <form action="../meeting/attendance" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="venue" value="${meeting.id}" />
                        <input type="submit" name="attendance" value="attend" />
                        <input type="submit" name="attendance" value="reject" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:when>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, your class does not have such property. It does have the `inviteStatus` property.

```
public InviteStatus getInviteStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

PROPERTIES ARE BASED IN GETTERS. The name of the internal value that stores the data is not relevant.

Comment: Additionally, limit the scope of your questions. If it is a JSP question, it does not matter if the bean is provided by JPA or Hibernate or hardcoded in your code. You may want to check http://sscce.org